# Setting the Windows Forms ToolStripMenuItem ShortcutKeys property to numpad key does not work

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

We have the ability to define shortcut keys for Windows Forms application menu items. That way I can tell a menu item *File->Save* to have the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and the menu item's handler is "magically" executed after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

The trouble is with the numeric keypad keys, the `ShortcutKey` property does not accept them (I don't understand how are they different from the other acceptable keys).

MSDN states that the property accepts type *System.Windows.Forms.Keys* (One of the Keys values. The default is None.); and an `InvalidEnumArgumentException` would be thrown when the parameter is not one of *Keys* values. But for example Keys.Divide **IS** one of Keys values, and yet it can't be used.

So how can I set a menu item to have a shortcut for Numpad `*` or Numpad `+`? Do I need to handle the key in Form's *ProcessCmdKey* event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> in shortcuts.

example:

```
//working:  
toolStripMenuItem1.ShortcutKeys = Keys.Control | Keys.NumPad0;  
//throws exception  
toolStripMenuItem1.ShortcutKeys = Keys.NumPad0;
```

Comment: that makes sense, when I think about it.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question about using Numpad `*` and Numpad `+`:

- Numpad `*` is called the multiply key. The enumeration name is `Multiply`.
- Numpad `+` is called the add key. The enumeration name is `Add`.
- Numpad `-` is called the subtract key. The enumeration name is `Subtract`.

It is not possible to select these in Visual Studio's property window (at least not in Visual Studio 2008), but the corresponding source code can be edited; where property `ShortcutKeys` is set. For example for Numpad `+` for a menu item named `mnuMoreTime`:

```
this.mnuMoreTime.ShortcutKeys = 
    ((System.Windows.Forms.Keys)((System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Control |
                                  System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Add)));
```