# C# - shortcut Shift + some char not compiling

Tags: c#, winforms, shortcut

I work in Visual Studio 2008 (framework 3.5) and I am trying to add shortcut (for example <kbd>Shift</kbd> + 
<kbd>D</kbd>) to menuStrip (exactly to toolStrip in menuStrip) but I can´t. I get error:

> "The value of argument 'value' (65604) is invalid for Enum type `Keys`.

Parameter name: value". It shows just with <kbd>Shift</kbd>. With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> it´s ok. Even when I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> then it worked but not with just <kbd>Shift</kbd> and letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use shift and a letter, digit or other character as a shortcut key, since the shift key works as a [modifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifier_key) -- it'd be like typing <kbd>A</kbd> when you really meant <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

**EDIT:** I didn't find anything in the docs that stated it, but in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708909/setting-the-windows-forms-toolstripmenuitem-shortcutkeys-property-to-numpad-key-d) it's stated that you can only use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>alt</kbd> in combination with a letter or digit. Though, you can of course use <kbd>shift</kbd> with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>alt</kbd> in any combination with another key!

Comment: Thanks, I forget about using shift to capital letters but now it´s logical why it´s not working.

Answer (score 0):

The shift key is a [modifier key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifier_key) on a keyboard, used to type capital letters and other alternate "upper" characters. It can only be used for shortcuts in conjunction with keys which do not have any alternate usages.

Comment: But I think `Ctrl` and `Alt` are modifiers as well. So it's the 'D' that's rejected (as too simple).

Answer (score 0):

You Could override it. It would let you use <kbd>Shift</kbd> with other keys, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> n such. I ended up with the same problem and this is how I solved my problem :

```
public class ExtendedTabControl: TabControl
{
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Tab))
        {
            // Write custom logic here
            return true;
        }
        if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Shift | Keys.Tab))
        {
            // Write custom logic here
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps