# How to: Assign Keys.PageUp to ToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeys

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
ToolStripMenuItem mi = new ToolStripMenuItem();
var value = new KeysConverter().ConvertFromString("PageUp");
// value = Enum.Parse(typeof (Keys), "PageUp");
var cast = (Keys) value;
mi.ShortcutKeys = cast;
```

I'm trying to convert the string "PageUp" into the appropriate `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` value. 
However, both parsing approaches (`Enum.Parse()` vs. `KeysConverter.ConvertFromString()`) set `value` to `LButton | Space`, which leads to an `InvalidEnumArgumentException` on the last line.

Background:

- `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` is a Flags enum
- PageUp has a value of 33, LButton is 1, Space is 32 ==> meaning `Enum.Parse` works correctly.

How do I correctly parse "PageUp" into `Keys.PageUp`?

---

**Update:**
Silly me. the parsing works correctly.

```
ToolStripMenuItem mi = new ToolStripMenuItem();
mi.ShortcutKeys = Keys.PageUp;
```

but this one throws the above mentioned exception.
So after realising I barked up the wrong tree:

How can one assign `Keys.PageUp` to `ToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeys`?

Comment: clarification: I noticed the 'Caution' and 'Remarks' on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx and figured out as much myself. I still don't know how to correctly parse this - apart from possibly shipping my own

Comment: as always: Would you please have the courtesy to post a comment why you downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, `ShortcutKeys` uses this logic to accept possible shortcut keys (however, None is always accepted):

```
public static bool IsValidShortcut(Keys shortcut) { 
    // should have a key and one or more modifiers.

    Keys keyCode = (Keys)(shortcut & Keys.KeyCode); 
    Keys modifiers = (Keys)(shortcut & Keys.Modifiers);

    if (shortcut == Keys.None) {
        return false;
    }
    else if ((keyCode == Keys.Delete) || (keyCode == Keys.Insert)) { 
        return true;
    } 
    else if (((int)keyCode >= (int)Keys.F1) && ((int)keyCode <= (int)Keys.F24)) { 
        // function keys by themselves are valid
        return true; 
    }
    else if ((keyCode != Keys.None) && (modifiers != Keys.None)) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case Keys.Menu: 
            case Keys.ControlKey:
            case Keys.ShiftKey: 
                // shift, control and alt arent valid on their own. 
                return false;
            default: 
                if (modifiers == Keys.Shift) {
                    // shift + somekey isnt a valid modifier either
                    return false;
                } 
                return true;
        } 
    } 
    // has to have a valid keycode and valid modifier.
    return false; 
}
```

So you can use, `None`, `Delete`, `Insert`, `F1`-`F12` keys on their own, or all other keys with `Alt`, `Ctrl`, and, only as additional, `Shift` key modifier.

Answer (score 2):

The second you are asking the right question, you'll find the answer....

this one clarified it for me: 
[Setting the Windows Forms ToolStripMenuItem ShortcutKeys property to numpad key does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708909/setting-the-windows-forms-toolstripmenuitem-shortcutkeys-property-to-numpad-key)

**quote** from the accepted answer there:
You must use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> in shortcuts.